# memory corruption error during allocation

Tags: c++, qt, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

my code in `C++` using `QT` gives me `memory corruption` error when I go through this part of the code:

```
 for (int vid=0;vid<m_trajs.size();vid++)
{
    QVector<int*> clusterIDs_foronevideo;
    for (int level=0;level<nbClusters.size();level++)
    {

        int* clusterIDs_atonelevel = new int [long_vals[vid]];
        for (int ind=0;ind<stInd[vid];ind++)
        {

            clusterIDs_atonelevel[ind] = clusterIDs[level][ind];

        }

        clusterIDs_foronevideo << clusterIDs_atonelevel;


    }
    m_clusterIDs << clusterIDs_foronevideo;

}
```

`long_vals` is just an array holding number of my IDs at each processing level.
I am not getting error at the first iteration of the `for loop` it appears like in `vid = 5`. I used delete also right after this line `clusterIDs_foronevideo << clusterIDs_atonelevel;` but I also got error while I am doing delete.
what is wrong with my code, however the size I want to allocate is also small. 
this is the error shows up in command line

```
malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0000000000cd5e00 ***
```

and this is while I am not using malloc here

Comment: `for (int ind=0;ind<stInd[vid];ind++)` why `stInd[vid]`? You should use `long_vals[vid]`

Comment: Use vectors and a good debug compiler and it will alert you when you go out of bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely that you allocate `long_vals[vid]` number of int's, but then loop `stInd[vid]` number of times. If the later is bigger than the former, you're accessing memory outside the allocated region and you're likely overwriting some memory that's used by another `malloc`'d region.

You should do something like:

```
int count = stInd[vid];
// Or maybe: int count = long_vals[vid];
int* clusterIDs_atonelevel = new int[count];
for (int ind=0; ind<count; ind++) {
    ...
}
```